# How to create Custom Listener to a file in android

Tags: android, listener

I have created a server application which will send data to client. That data may be regarding contacts, time zone etc. But when the client receives the data the client inserts all the data in a temporary file. I want to write my own listeners if the newly entered data contains time zone then immediately form certain type of activity. means i want to perform different actions as per message received. i want to put listener on the file. which will notify me when ever specific type of data is entered. How can i achieve this.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

How about using broadcast of a custom action? for example broadcast a action of ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED and those that are "listening" or interested for the event will register a receiver for the action?

Comment: Can we create any custom listener in android. in java we can create our custom listener for swing application. similarly can we do for android?

Comment: yes you can. register a receiver using the Context.registerReceiver method with the IntentFilter created from your custom action name.